# Cannot attach file in jsseprovider, gmailsender

Tags: java, android

I am trying this code. I am able to send a mail with the following code, but when i insert attachment code (you can see between //CODE FROM HERE to //CODE TILL HERE) it is showing error

> in sending: javax.mail.SendFailedException: No recipient addresses

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
try {

    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setDataHandler(handler);
//CODE FROM HERE 
    Multipart emailContent = new MimeMultipart();

    //Text body part
    MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    textBodyPart.setText("My multipart text");

    //Attachment body part.
    MimeBodyPart pdfAttachment = new MimeBodyPart();
    clienttargetPdf = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/mm.pdf";
    pdfAttachment.attachFile(clienttargetPdf);

    //Attach body parts
    emailContent.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
    emailContent.addBodyPart(pdfAttachment);

    //Attach multipart to message
    message.setContent(emailContent);

    Transport.send(message);
//CODE TILL HERE.  

    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
    else
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
    Transport.send(message);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("mylog", "Error in sending: " + e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your problem is here, when you're trying to send the message already:

```
    Transport.send(message);
//CODE TILL HERE.
```

But it should actually be sent few rows later, after setting recipients:

```
//CODE TILL HERE.  

    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
    else
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
    Transport.send(message);   // <---- here's the second sending
```